# Installing nodeJS

Tags: node.js

I install nodeJS like here shown: http://nodeguide.com/beginner.html

I have done these steps: `wget http://nodejs.org/dist/node-v0.4.4.tar.gz` and `tar -xzf node-v0.4.4.tar.gz`

But when I try this: cd node-v0.4.4.tar.gz it gives me an error: `sh: line 0: cd: node-v0.4.4.tar.gz: Not a directory`

And when I try this: `./configure` it gives me `sh: ./configure: No such file or directory`

And finally when I try `sudo make install` it says `sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`

**Thank you very much**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to unzip the file before untarring it.

```
gzip -d node-v0.4.4.tar.gz
tar -xvf node-v0.4.4.tar
cd node-v0.4.4
./configure
```

Comment: @Matthieu Cormier: it helped me, but when I try ./configure it gives me `sh: ./configure: No such file or directory`

Comment: try changing the permissions of the file with chmod 755 configure

Comment: @Matthieu Cormier: through ftp or where?

Comment: if you do ls do you see the configure file?

Comment: @Matthieu Cormier: no, I don't see it in ftp.

Comment: Are you doing this remotely, on an ftp client?

Comment: @tladuke: through command line

Answer (score 2):

There is more simpler way:

```
$ sudo pip install nodeenv

# install latest node.js in sandbox
$ nodeenv test-node-env

# activate sandbox environment
$ source ./test-node-env/bin/activate

# work in sandbox
(test-node-env) $ node -v
v0.4.6
```

[nodeenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/nodeenv/) - virtual environment for node.js

Comment: @shorrty: sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo

Answer (score 1):

> cd node-v0.4.4.tar.gz

node-v0.4.4.tar.gz is a file, not a directory that you can go into. Running

```
tar -xzf node-v0.4.4.tar.gz
```

should uncompress the tar.gz into a directory with a similar name.

Comment: @tladuke: I have done that, still the same error.

Comment: works for me. maybe it didn't download completely.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend using nvm: https://github.com/creationix/nvm

nvm lets you install multiple versions of node and switch between them. It is as simple as this:

```
git clone git://github.com/creationix/nvm.git ~/.nvm
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
nvm install v0.4.7
nvm use v0.4.7
```

don't forget to add `~/.nvm/nvm.sh` to your path so that you can use it in later sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same problem, and it was as simple as the download didn't complete, so it hadn't downloaded configure.  Try starting from scratch and it should download configure along with the rest, and then when you do ./configure it should work.

If, after you cd into the directory starting with "node" (NOT the .tar.gz file, but rather the directory with almost the same name that was created by the "tar -xzf" command) and "ls", it doesn't show any file or directory called "configure", then it didn't all download, so go get the .tar.gz file again.

Answer (score 0):

You probably downloaded the binary (compiled) version of nodejs when you download it from the nodejs.org [download page](http://nodejs.org/download/). It might be a bit confusing, since the downloaded archive's README.md file states that you should run `./configure` as one of the steps needed to install nodejs on your system.

If you want to build nodejs yourself, you should rather [download](https://github.com/joyent/node/archive/master.zip) the archive from the [github project page](https://github.com/joyent/node). The downloaded archive will contain the *configure* script and you will be able to install nodejs by following the steps mentioned in the included README.md file.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu, I prefer to install Node using NPM and **n**, which is a node version manager that you can get through NPM! It's very easy to get node like this (and you will probably want NPM anyway.) From the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install -y npm
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n lts
```