# How to install Arm 7 distribution of Nodejs

Tags: ubuntu, node.js, arm

Nodejs provides pre-built binaries for ARM7:

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/

There's nothing in the readme about installation on ARM7. How can I ensure node and npm are installed globally. Is it just a matter of adding some symlinks to `/usr/local/bin` ?

OS is Ubuntu-Mate 15.04 on Raspberry Pi 2. apt-get installs a much older version of node.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing nodeJS](http://superuser.com/questions/273962/installing-nodejs)

Comment: The installation procedure for applications on the Ubuntu MATE for the Raspberry Pi 2 is the same as that for the regular desktop version, i.e. using apt-get. Even so I don't think this question is a duplicate because the linked duplicate question is not up-to-date, so it doesn't answer your question. This answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/328681/installing-the-latest-node-js-mongodb/668006#668006 is less than one month old, and I think it will work better on your Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

You may download the binaries from nodejs.org and untar them anywhere to your system. Each tar has at least the node binary and a compatible npm.

So you may untar different versions to e.g. `/usr/local/lib/node` like `/usr/local/node/release/v0.10.45`.

Then you can run `node` by using full path `/usr/local/lib/node/v0.10.45/bin/node --version` or set $PATH `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/lib/node/v0.10.45/bin node --version` or do a symlink.